# Proving that the upper triangular group of matrices is not normal for any matrix dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-groups

Consider the group $ GL_{n}\left(\mathbb{F}\right) $ of the invertible matrices of dimensions $n \times n $ over the field $\mathbb{F} $.

Now consider its subgroup $ B_{n}\left(\mathbb{F}\right)\leq GL_{n}\left(\mathbb{F}\right) $, of the upper triangular invertible matrices.

I want to prove that this group is not normal for any $ n \in \mathbb{N} $. Now, for $ n=2 $ it is pretty easy find a counter example (the first one I came up with - worked). But I want to know whether or not exists $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ B_{n}\left(\mathbb{F}\right) $ actually is a normal subgroup.

In order to prove that this subgroup is normal, I have to show that for any invertible matrix $ A $ the following holds $ AB_{n}\left(\mathbb{F}\right)A^{-1}=B_{n}\left(\mathbb{F}\right) $

(Where $ AB_{n}\left(\mathbb{F}\right)=\left\{ AB:B\in B_{n}\left(\mathbb{F}\right)\right\}  $ if you're not familier with the notation that Im familier with).

And actually, it is enough to show that $ AB_{n}\left(\mathbb{F}\right)A^{-1}\subseteq B_{n}\left(\mathbb{F}\right) $ (For any invertible A).

So that in order to prove that for any $n$ this subgroup is not normal, I have to find a matrix $ A,B $ such that $ ABA^{-1} $ is not upper triangular, for general $ n $ dimension. Now, my first thought was to fight those indices and just use the definition of matrix multipication, invertible matrix through the adjoint definition, and then maybe I could explain how to choose the matrix enteries so it would work. But it seems not elegant at all and I'd probably get lost on the way with those indices.

How can I prove it for a general $n$?

Comment: Actually it follows from the $n=2$ case. Just embed your example in the top-left 2 x 2 subsquare. Higher-level view: there is a subgroup of $GL_n(F)$ isomorphic to $GL_2(F)$ and such that $GL_2(F) \cap B_n(F) = B_2(F)$, and if $B_n(F)$ were normal in $GL_n(F)$ then so would be $B_2(F)$ in $GL_2(F)$.

Comment: Alternatively, let $P$ be the "antidiagonal" matrix, i.e., $P_{ij} = 1$ if $i + j = n+1$ and 0 elsewhere. Can you see what the map $A \mapsto PAP^{-1}$ is?

Comment: You ought to know that a change of basis will transform the matrices $X\in B_n$  to $S^{-1}XS$ [for the same $S$]. Now all the matrices in $B_n$ have the first basis element as an eigenvector.  But that will not be true for $S^{-1}B_n S$ (provided we don't move the first basis element to a multiple of itsself.)